# Has David Davis accepted that we must have straight bananas?

Tags: brexit

*David Davis [Minister for Leaving the EU] said the UK wanted to lead a "global race to the top" in rights and standards not, as some feared, a "competitive race to the bottom".* (Tonight's BBC News)

**Does this mean that the Brexit wing of the UK Government have accepted 
that we must have straight bananas? Is it a case of *plus ça change, plus c'est la même chose?***

(This refers to the oft-repeated claim during the EU Referendum debate, that Brussels officials mandated among many other such ridiculous things, that all bananas on sale must be straight? David Davis the British Minister who has today emphasised that Britain will protect standards, was a leading Brexit campaigner, wedded to a belief that the EU enforced ridiculous rules. See Commission Regulation (EC) 2257/94 on fruit and vegetables requiring [Bananas must be free from abnormal curvature](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/unitedkingdom/en/media/euromyths/bendybananas.html)" (often parodied as a [ban on curved bananas](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2017/feb/05/brexit-donald-trump-trade-deal-bendy-bananas-stewart-lee)))

Comment: You might want to explain this in more detail. It's not clear at all what you're asking

Comment: @Machavity Are you not familiar with the oft-repeated claim during the EU Referendum debate which said that Brussels officials mandated among many other such ridiculous things, that all bananas on sale must be straight? David Davis the British Minister who has today emphasised that Britain will protect standards, was a leading Brexit campaigner, wedded to a belief that the EU enforced ridiculous rules.

Comment: @WS2 I think adding that comment to the body would help the question, I've never heard of David Davis before now.

Comment: So it's not actually a pun? I've spent an hour trying to puzzle it out. I may need to stop reading Purim Torah.

Comment: @WS2 In general you should assume nobody is familiar with the topic (I live in the US and don't follow EU or UK politics that closely). A link and some quotes would go a long way to making this on-topic. Voted to close for now

Comment: I've edited, hopefully this is in line with the OP intentions, but makes the question clearer.

Comment: @Machavity I'm quite surprised that people who, understandably, know nothing about the topic, nevertheless take action to close the question. I see issues raised here concerning countries like India, which I know little about. But I wouldn't dream of voting to close one, simply because of my own ignorance.

Comment: @JamesK Whilst I appreciate your trouble in editing, I feel the question, which was asked with tongue in cheek, loses some of its impact. So I am editing your edit, if you don't mind.

Comment: @WS2 We're not trying to be mean or anal. But without some context, this would be little more than an inside political joke. And the edit is sufficient to reopen. Good luck!

Comment: It is unlikely that this question can be answered with quotes from the relevant politicians, especially given there are unlikely to be any quotes since the 2016 vote that discuss bananas.  (Besides, I like my curved bananas!)

Comment: I think this type of question/joke is better suited for the pub at Friday night, and not so much this site. Contrived questions just to prove a point don't work too well here.

Comment: Because, why not:  https://www.amazon.com/Hutzler-571-Banana-Slicer/dp/B0047E0EII#customerReviews

Comment: So what you ask is if Davis wants UK to keep on going towards trading standards? This can already be deduced from what he says at the article you quoted. Is there a reason to then ask this other than trying to make a joke?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Just FYI, [Meta seems to have OKed political joke questions](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2775/is-it-off-topic-to-ask-about-rationale-behind-political-satire). It might not be a great question, but I think it can stand up to the rules

Comment: @Machavity As I read it, that is about something else entirely? That meta question is about explaining a politically themed joke someone else made, not about using this site to make your own joke questions. Besides, meta isn't exactly "rules", especially not when the top post is a +3/-1 (not exactly a broad consensus).

Answer (score 8):

It's not clear what the UK government wants to commit to.

The "straight bananas" rule is actually a classic Euro Myth. The rule was a British one, already part of British law. The EU noticed that most EU countries had very similar laws on the import of bananas and that harmonizing them would ease trade with non-EU banana producing countries as well as movement of bananas within the EU, so adopted the British rules.

The government is currently proposing some kind of "regulatory alignment". This was agreed last year and is currently being written into a legally binding document that the UK will sign before moving on to trade talks with the EU.

However, the exact meaning of "regulatory alignment" has yet to be determined, and it may be cancelled in the event of a "no deal" crash-out. But in principle it appears that the intent of this agreement is for the UK to maintain alignment with all EU regulations now and in the future, in order to keep the Irish border open and friction free.

Comment: Any reference to the (pre-EU) UK regulation about bananas?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqVJEZnYiZo

Comment: Thank you. Coincidentally I have just discovered QI and I have been watching old episodes (did not get to that yet) to improve my English (I have to admit that I find them way more difficult to understand than talk shows from the USA).

Comment: AFAIK there was never a rule about straight bananas. However, there is a guideline that cucumbers should be straight. This may seem strange to younger readers, but in my youth cucumbers were as bent as bananas. The guideline was not dreamed up by some linearly-obsessed bureaucrat, but by the supermarket lobby, because straight cucumbers are easier to pack in boxes.

Comment: The rule is actually Commission Regulation 2257/94, which actually only sets out the classifications for bananas. The bendy ones can still be sold, they are just a lower classification. And as I say, when the regulation came in nothing actually changed in the UK because it was pretty much copy/pasted from our laws.

Comment: @user Ironically that video says "This video contains content from Fremantle International, who has blocked it in your country on copyright grounds" for me in the UK :-/

Comment: Does *anyone* know which specific act of parliament regulated banana shape?